# Why do Artinian rings have dimension 0 and not 1?

Tags: commutative-algebra, ring-theory

One of the properties of an Artinian ring $R$ is that every prime ideal is maximal. So, if $\mathfrak{m}$ is a nonzero prime ideal, $(0)\subseteq \mathfrak{m}$ is a length-$1$ chain of prime ideals, meaning that $\dim R\geq 1$. Since every prime ideal is maximal, no longer chains exist, meaning $\dim R=1$. But Artinian rings are supposed to have dimension $0$. What am I missing?

Comment: 0 need not be prime in an Artin ring.

Comment: Therefore, an artin ring where (0) is prime (hence maximal) is a field.

Comment: @dc2814 Perhaps you should put those thoughts you have expressed via comments in an answer.

Comment: a bit late comment but: Then a lot of artianian rings are not integral domains

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Being an Artin ring does not require that $(0)$ is a prime ideal. In fact, if $(0)$ is prime in the Artin ring $R\neq 0$, then $(0)$ is the only maximal ideal in $R$. Therefore $R$ is a field since every nonzero element is not contained in a maximal ideal, hence they are all units.